# Floating Action Button jumps up and down when snackbar animation begins

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I wanted to add an UNDO functionality after item is deleted in my Notes application. I added a snackbar to android ItemTouchHelper onSwiped method in which I delete single notes. The issue I am facing is that the Snackbar slide animation causes the floating action button to jump up and down again as the animation starts. I foud this issue described on Github forum [Github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/851) and [Animation](https://streamable.com/s4unf) ,unfortunatelly the issue wasn't resolved.

My activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_item" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

onSwiped

```
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                Note deletedNote = adapter.getNoteAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                noteViewModel.delete(deletedNote);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Note deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                noteViewModel.insert(deletedNote);
                            }
                        });
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in [Material-Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1036), you can workaround it either by using an older version of the library (1.1.0-alpha10), or give up the sliding animation and use a fade animation instead as follows

```
<style name="MySnackbarStyle" parent="Widget.Design.Snackbar">
  <item name="animationMode">fade</item>
</style>
```

and add the following to your activity's theme

```
<item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbarStyle</item>
```

Comment: Both suggestions worked, thank you very much for you time and help

Comment: Fade works fine too, but if you prefer the slide animation, check out my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Have found a simple solution. Took me really long.

It prevents the FAB from changing it's position before the animation of the snackbar begins.

Just add a new **SnackbarJumpFix** class to your project:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

public class SnackbarJumpFix extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    public SnackbarJumpFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        super.onDependentViewRemoved(parent, child, dependency);
        child.setTranslationY(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        if (dependency.getTranslationY() != 0) {
            child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity layout file add add this line to the **FAB**:

```
app:layout_behavior=".SnackbarJumpFix"
```